# How to modularize a Linked List?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have the following Linked List:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data; // Linked List type of data.
    struct Node *next; // Pointer to the next Node.
};

void printfList(struct Node *head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d\n", head -> data);
        head = head -> next;
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct Node *head   = NULL;
    struct Node *second = NULL;
    struct Node *third  = NULL;

    head   = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third  = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head -> data = 1;
    head -> next = second;

    second -> data = 2;
    second -> next = third;

    third -> data = 3;
    third -> next = NULL;

    printfList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I modularize this example to get something more professional? node type and separated from the others and function separately?

Comment: I don't see anything needing "modularization" here.

Comment: I suspect that if you could articulate what you think is unprofessional about the code presented, you would be at least half way to resolving that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think by "modularize" here you mean more kinda professional, clean looking code, I came up with following :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data; // Linked List type of data.
    struct Node *next; // Pointer to the next Node.
};
struct Node * makeNode(int data){
    struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
void printfList(struct Node *head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d\n", head -> data);
        head = head -> next;
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct Node *head, *prev;
    int i, n;
    printf("How many values you want to insert ?");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nNow enter values :\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int val;
        scanf("%d", &val);
        if(i == 0){
            head = makeNode(val);
            prev = head;
        }
        else{
            struct Node *temp = makeNode(val);
            prev->next = temp;
            prev = temp;
        }
    }

    printfList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that `struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` could be simplified to `struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);`

Comment: yeah, but that way it looks more "professional" i guess :P

Comment: Casting result of `malloc` is anything but "professional".

Comment: If the OP truly just means he wants to style his code in a way that looks more professional ... according to *somebody* ... then the question is primarily opinion-based and should be closed on those grounds, not answered.  I suspect he has something more specific in mind, but I'm not inclined to guess (much less answer) until he tells us what it is.

Comment: Also you should not mix function declaration and implementation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking to do, but I think you should start by reviewing the question: should a `"node"` be a property of an object (a `struct` data type) or should a `"node"` be an accessor to a data type...?

Both work and I've used both.

When I need to link **existing** objects together, than a node will contain a reference data type... but unlike your list, the data is always accessed using a pointer (not containing the actual data type, but only using a reference).

This allows one (object) to many (lists) relationships.

However, many times the data type itself will need to be "chained" (in a single list - one to one relationship), in which case the "node" is a property of the data type and can be re-used in many different types.

#### A list to link existing types

Here's an example code where I used a linked list to link existing objects using a `void` pointer.

I'm not sure this implementation adds anything to your initial concept, but it does show the "modularization" for a "one (objet) to many (lists)" approach.

```
/* *****************************************************************************
Simple List
***************************************************************************** */

typedef struct fio_ls_s {
  struct fio_ls_s *prev;
  struct fio_ls_s *next;
  void *obj;
} fio_ls_s;

#define FIO_LS_INIT(name)                                                      \
  { .next = &(name), .prev = &(name) }

/** Adds an object to the list's head. */
static inline __attribute__((unused)) void fio_ls_push(fio_ls_s *pos,
                                                       void *obj) {
  /* prepare item */
  fio_ls_s *item = (fio_ls_s *)malloc(sizeof(*item));
  if (!item)
    perror("ERROR: fiobj list couldn't allocate memory"), exit(errno);
  *item = (fio_ls_s){.prev = pos, .next = pos->next, .obj = obj};
  /* inject item */
  pos->next->prev = item;
  pos->next = item;
}

/** Adds an object to the list's tail. */
static inline __attribute__((unused)) void fio_ls_unshift(fio_ls_s *pos,
                                                          void *obj) {
  pos = pos->prev;
  fio_ls_push(pos, obj);
}

/** Removes an object from the list's head. */
static inline __attribute__((unused)) void *fio_ls_pop(fio_ls_s *list) {
  if (list->next == list)
    return NULL;
  fio_ls_s *item = list->next;
  void *ret = item->obj;
  list->next = item->next;
  list->next->prev = list;
  free(item);
  return ret;
}

/** Removes an object from the list's tail. */
static inline __attribute__((unused)) void *fio_ls_shift(fio_ls_s *list) {
  if (list->prev == list)
    return NULL;
  fio_ls_s *item = list->prev;
  void *ret = item->obj;
  list->prev = item->prev;
  list->prev->next = list;
  free(item);
  return ret;
}

/** Removes an object from the containing node. */
static inline __attribute__((unused)) void *fio_ls_remove(fio_ls_s *node) {
  void *ret = node->obj;
  node->next->prev = node->prev->next;
  node->prev->next = node->next->prev;
  free(node);
  return ret;
}
```

#### A list that is integrated in the data-type

Often I have objects that I know I will link together and that by nature will only belong to a single list ("one to one").

In these cases, placing the `node` struct data within the data-type allows better locality and improved performance through a single allocation for both the data and the node information.

A good enough example for such a situation can be examined is [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44774481/4025095).

Comment: If you're not sure what he's looking to do (which I'm not, either) then it seems that the first order of business ought to be to clear that up.  Only by sheer luck can you answer a question when you don't know what the question *is*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I agree. I started out with a comment about the meaning of "modularize" and the question of encapsulation... but it got a bit long. I ended up thinking this longer "answer" might provide OP with a better understanding of different approaches to "modularization" and perhaps help sharpen the question.