# Searching for files in a directory by name using Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, search, directory

I'm trying to create a program where I can search for some files in a directory on my PC, using Visual Studio C++.
As I'm not very experienced with that, I found this code (below) in another answer but couldn't find any explanation to the code.
I'm having a hard time figuring it out and would strongly appreciate any help possible.

If there's another way of doing this I would be pleased to know how.
Thank you!

"
Now you can get file names. Just compare a file name.

```
 while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
       std::string fname = dirp->d_name;
       if(fname.find("abc") != std::string::npos)
          files.push_back(fname);
    }
```

Also you can use scandir function which can register filter function.

```
 static int filter(const struct dirent* dir_ent)
    {
        if (!strcmp(dir_ent->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dir_ent->d_name, "..")) 
    return 0;
        std::string fname = dir_ent->d_name;

        if (fname.find("abc") == std::string::npos) return 0;

        return 1;
    }


    int main()
    {
        struct dirent **namelist;

        std::vector<std::string> v;
        std::vector<std::string>::iterator  it;

        n = scandir( dir_path , &namelist, *filter, alphasort );

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            std::string fname = namelist[i]->d_name;

            v.push_back(fname);

            free(namelist[i]);
        }
        free(namelist);

    return 0;
    }
```

"

Comment: It's not clear what you can't figure out. Can you be more specific about which parts you don't follow? Or what's going wrong (if anything)?

Comment: Sure. I copied the lower piece of code ( from -> static int filter(const to -> return 0;} ) and pasted it as is in my code. I then tried to apply it to my case. The problem is that I don't know which pieces I should change (for example "abc" change it to the name of the file I am searching for) to apply it to my case. Also, what output should I expect?

Comment: In `main` you don't appear to be using the `it` and perhaps you should write out the contents of `v` to see what it gets?

Comment: Are you unsure what the `find` method on string does? Is the question really what to put in the filter function?

Comment: Where should I use  "it" and what should I write as a content for "v"?

Comment: I really have no idea what the find and filter function do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way of doing this would probably be using the new [`std::filesystem` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). [`directory_iterators`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) allow you to go through the contents of a directory. Since they are just iterators, you can combine them with standard algorithms like [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to search for a particular entry:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void search(const fs::path& directory, const fs::path& file_name)
{
    auto d = fs::directory_iterator(directory);

    auto found = std::find_if(d, end(d), [&file_name](const auto& dir_entry)
    {
        return dir_entry.path().filename() == file_name;
    });

    if (found != end(d))
    {
        // we have found what we were looking for
    }

    // ...
}
```

We first create a `directory_iterator` `d` for the directory in which we want to search. We then use `std::find_if()` to go through the contents of the directory and search for an entry that matches the filename we are looking for. `std::find_if()` expects a function object as last argument that is applied to every visited element and returns `true` if the element matches what we are looking for. `std::find_if()` returns the iterator to the first element for which this predicate function returns `true`, otherwise it returns the end iterator. Here, we use a lambda as predicate that returns `true` when the filename component of the path of the directory entry we're looking at matches the wanted filename. Afterwards, we compare the iterator returned by `std::find_if()` to the end iterator to see if we have found an entry or not. In case we did find an entry, `*found` will evaluate to a [`directory_entry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry) representing the respective file system object.

Note that this will require a recent version of Visual Studio 2017. Don't forget to set the language standard to `/std:c++17` or `/std:c++latest` in the project properties (C++/Language).

Comment: Great, can you provide me with a little more explanation on what the above code does?

Comment: I've edited my answer, simplified the code a little, and added more explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The program worked. However, this worked only when I gave the exact directory (with no sub directory). In my case, I have a big folder e.g folder A. This folder contains different sub-folders called B C D. In each sub-folder are another bunch of sub-folders before finally accessing the different files of different formats. Can you advise on how to modify the code so that it goes through all the sub-folders?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if I passed the right parameters to the function search. Is the following correct? search("C:\\FolderA\\FolderB\\FolderF" , "file-name");

Comment: Simply use a `recursive_directory_iterator` instead of a normal `directory_iterator`. The recursive one will visit the directory and all subdirectories. And yes, this way of calling it should work.

Comment: Great it actually worked. Now one thing that was nice in the first code I posted in my initial question, is that I could search for example "1234" without searching for the exact name which is "1234_0506AB". Any idea how I can integrate that into the recursive code? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, instead of simply testing for equality via `dir_entry.path().filename() == file_name`, just get the filename as string `dir_entry.path().filename().string()` and do a `.find()`. For even more general searching, you could use a regex and match that with the filename…

Answer (score 0):

Both methods use the `find` function of a `std::string`:

```
   fname.find("abc")
```

This looks for `"abc"` in the `fname` string. If it's found it returns the index it starts at, otherwise it retruns `std::string::npos`, so they both check for that substring.

You may want to see if you have an *exact* match, using `==` instead. It depends.

If an appropriate filename is found, it's pushed back into a vector.
Your main function has

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator  it;
```

which it doesn't use.
I suspect that came over with some copy/paste.

You can use a range based `for` loop to see what's in your vector:

```
for(const std::string & name : v)
{
    std::cout << name << '\n';
}
```

The `filter` function also checks against `"."` and `".."` since these have special meanings - current dir and up one dir.
At that point, th C API has returned a `char *`, so they use `strcmp`, rather than std::string methods.

---

Edit:

```
n = scandir( dir_path , &namelist, *filter, alphasort );
```

uses `n` which you haven't declared.
Try

```
int n = scandir( dir_path , &namelist, *filter, alphasort );
```

Also, that uses `dir_path` which needs declaring somewhere.

For a quick fix, try

```
const char * dir_path = "C:\\";
```

(or whatever path you want, watching out for escaping backslashes with an extra backslash.

You probably want to pass this in as an `arg` to main.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The program worked. However, this worked only when I gave the exact directory (with no sub directory). In my case, I have a big folder e.g folder A. This folder contains different sub-folders called B C D. In each sub-folder are another bunch of sub-folders before finally accessing the different files of different formats. Can you advise on how to modify the code so that it goes through all the sub-folders?

Comment: If you find a directory (look in `namelist[i]`) you can recusive i.e. invoke your search down that dir e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436841/how-to-recursively-list-directories-in-c-on-linux but you will then need to pull the code out of `main` into a function