# recursive search for a file with a certain extension...C language

Tags: c, recursion, system-calls

Can anyone suggest me how to do a recursive search for a file with a certain extension using system calls?I should use opendir() but I don't quite understand how it works and how to use it recursively.

Comment: What don´t you understand in particular? Provide an example to show your where your issue is.

Comment: Maybe this will give you some idea how opendir works, https://github.com/b-k/21st-Century-Examples/blob/master/process_dir.c.

Comment: There is a difference between recursive (function calling itself) and iterative (function uses loop to perform several iterations of similar steps, eg. calling another function in a loop.)

Comment: When asking a question about system calls (or other OS specific things), you should always specify exactly which operating system you are targeting. For instance, i know there's an `opendir()` function in glibc (which would suggest you're using linux), but since i'm not familiar with Windows i don't know whether or not there's a function of the same name there. Specifying the OS makes it much easier for people to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: On Linux use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

*I should use opendir() but I don't quite understand how it works and how to use it recursively.*

Idiomatically, `opendir()` is not used *recursively*, rather it is used in conjunction with `readdir()` in a loop, *iteratively* to list files, which can include other directories.

An example of using opendir(), and readdir() in a loop to find files.  ([from here](https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=3246))

This example is directly from the link with the exception of the `strstr()` call, used to pull out the files with the extension you are looking for.  (See comment in code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{
    DIR *folder;
    struct dirent *entry;
    int files = 0;

    folder = opendir(".");
    if(folder == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to read directory");
        return(1);
    }

    while(entry=readdir(folder))
    {
        files++;
        if(strstr(entry->d_name, ".csv"))//Added to illustrate 
                                         //(change csv to extension you are looking for)
        {
            printf("File %3d: %s\n",
                files,
                entry->d_name);
        }

    }

    closedir(folder);

    return(0);
}
```

If you did indeed mean *recursively*, there are some [ideas how to do that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436841/how-to-recursively-list-directories-in-c-on-linux).