# Does Mono Unix/Posix have nftw/ftw?

Tags: linux, mono

I was going to use `opendir`/`readdir` for reading files, but an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29402705/455796) says [`nftw`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) is better. That function seems to be standard POSIX function from 2008, so it is not a new thing. However, I could not find it under `Mono.Posix.Syscall` or `Mono.Unix.Syscall`. Does `nftw` really not exist in Mono? If not, why does it not exist? If it was standardised 12 years ago, I do not think it is too new not to be included in Mono.

Comment: I don't know much about .NET/Mono, but would [this](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/) help your cause?

Comment: @tink Thanks. However, the `ntfw` function is very complicated (it takes a function pointer as a parameter, and that function needs a complex structure as a parameter, etc), so I don't think the hassle is worth for me in this case. If it is not available, I guess I will just use opendir/readdir which are provided by Mono Unix.