# Shell program in C how to run a compiled program that is in a subdirectory?

Tags: c, shell, compilation

I am building a simple shell program that does a few things. one requirement my professor is giving us is that once a program is compiled through the shell (just using cc) then the result, a.out, can be searched for if it is not in the directory you are currently in. I cannot find anything about doing this.

my code works fine to run it using ./a.out, I can also go into a subdirectory by doing ./test/a.out like normal. But I have no idea how I would go about having the shell search for the compiled program and run it from where it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. parts of the code are below.

Here is the commandhandler, the final else is what sends the code to be run

```
int commandHandler(char * args[]){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    
    int fileDesc;
    int standardOut;
    
    int aux;
    int background = 0;
    
    char *args_aux[256];
    
    //array for the arguments
    while ( args[j] != NULL){
        args_aux[j] = args[j];
        j++;
    }
    
    // 'quit' command quits the shell
    if(strcmp(args[0], "quit") == 0) {
        exit(0);
    }
    
    // 'pwd' command prints the current directory
    else if (strcmp(args[0], "pwd") == 0){
        printf("%s\n", getcwd(currentDirectory, 1024));
    } 
    
    // 'cd' command to change directory
    else if (strcmp(args[0], "cd") == 0) { 
        changeDirectory(args);
    }
    
    // 'delDir' command to delete a directory (works on directories that are not empty)
    else if (strcmp(args[0], "delDir") == 0) { 
        char* foldername = args[1];
         deleteDir(foldername);
    }

    //this is to run any specific program, like the i_did_it program!
    else {
        while (args[i] != NULL && background == 0){
            i++;
        }
        args_aux[i] = NULL;
        launchProg(args_aux, background);
        
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Then below is the launchProg function

```
void launchProg(char **args, int background) {   
     int err = -1;
     
     if((pid = fork()) == -1){
         printf("Child process could not be created\n");
         return;
     }
     //child process
    if(pid == 0){
        //child process ignores SIGINT signals  
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
        
        //set parent var to environment variable
        setenv("parent", getcwd(currentDirectory, 1024), 1);    
        
        // If a command does not exist
        if (execvp(args[0],args) == err){
            printf("Command not found");
            kill(getpid(),SIGTERM);
        }
     }
     
     //parent process
     if (background == 0) {
         waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
     }
     else {
         printf("Process created with PID: %d\n",pid);
     }   
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if `execvp` fails, why not simply call `exit()`? That's one normally ends processes. You should probably also print out the reason, using e.g. `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: *"one requirement my professor is giving us is that once a program is compiled through the shell (just using cc) then the result, a.out, can be searched for if it is not in the directory you are currently in."* - is this actually what your professor told you? Because that is a very vague and confusing requirement. Usually shells have an environment variable called `PATH` which contains a list of default paths to look for when searching for executables, I'm sure your prof means you should implement something like that.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli The requirement set by him is "It can look for the program if it is not located in the same directory as where your shell program is located, but in a child directory." It is pretty vague, I asked him to explain more but he was not very helpful. I believe it is up to me how to do this, so as long as it works, it doesn't matter how I did it

Comment: @user12763568 ok, that is a different story and it is surely possible to do, although not that simple. This is what you are looking for: [How to recursively list directories in C on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436841/how-to-recursively-list-directories-in-c-on-linux)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recursively list directories in C on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436841/how-to-recursively-list-directories-in-c-on-linux)