# Why am I able to include sys/*.h without linking any extra libraries?

Tags: c++, linker

I am new to C++ and am learning C90 as a pre-introduction to the language. I noticed that when I include an external header (such as an OpenGL header), I also need to include the binary library file containing the exports.

Anything included which is part of the C standard library is automatically added to my project, but I am able to include `sys/socket.h` without needing to explicitly define any extra library locations!

**Are the `sys/*.h` header files all included in the standard library on Unix by default or am I missing something?**

**Does the linker have to scan all libraries you include until it finds the right one with the correct definitions?**

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags for unrelated languages! C++ is not C; your text does not make any sense! 2) unclear. What is your problem? 3) Headers and linking are completely unrelated.

Comment: It's completely unecessary, and probably undesirable, to learn C before learning C++.

Comment: C is **not** an introduction to C++. Why do you use the C++ tag while asking a C90 question? You never need a library to include a header. You need a library to use functions declared in that header.

Comment: @manni66 Yes, and the functions defined in the `sys/socket.h` header can be included without a library - as I stated. It makes no sense why there aren't any errors as the C standard doesn't define these functions yet it seems to compile perfectly fine. Where is the actual definitions for these functions located and how is the linker locating them?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: It depends on what one wants to learn. If the target is to learn C, one should learn C (just not ancient C90, but modern C11, at worst C99). If one want to learn C++, it should be C++ (C++11/14/17 actually).

Comment: Why do you learn C90? Get a more recent book and learn modern C. C90 is outdated since 18 years!

Comment: @Olaf To see the roots of the language! I fully understand that C practices are bad in C++ and they share some syntax, but are different languages. I'm not going in-depth into learning C, I just want to get a fundamental grasp on the roots and behind the scenes first. I still don't understand how my declarations are linked unless the linker scans every single library on my system... perhaps answering questions is better than criticizing.

Comment: @TimothyRiddle: That's a wrong approach! If you want ot see the roots of the languages, you really should learn B and assembly language (PDP/11 IIRC). Get a good **recent** book and work through the chapters.

Comment: @Olaf I don't think you quite understand - I'm not looking to learn the language in-depth as I already said. I just wanted a knowledge of how the compilation works to generate executable files, static/dynamic libraries, etc. Any books you recommend on basics of compilation? I'm not writing a compiler so no over-complications. :)

Comment: I s Amazon down? Google? Stack Overflow? Please undertand we are not a tutoring site. Use your search skills. If there are none, you should learn how to search anyway, it's a vital skill nowadays.

Comment: @Olaf Well seeing as you don't seem to know the answer to the question, I guess I'll have to do that. Thanks anyways. :p

Comment: @TimothyRiddle if you don't use the function in **your** C code there is no need to link anything.

Answer (score 2):

The C POSIX library is a superset of the C standard library. After opening it up, it looks like the function definitions to the `sys/*.h` files are all there even though they aren't an explicit component of the original C standard.

The actual function definitions are included inside of the standard library on Unix.

Also found this, interesting read: [Difference between C standard library and C POSIX library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376837/difference-between-c-standard-library-and-c-posix-library)