# Anonymous shared memory?

Tags: posix, shared-memory

Is there a POSIX-y way to allocating shared memory that's not tied to a specific filename? I.e. memory that is shared between processes only by passing SCM_RIGHTS messages via UNIX domain sockets?

Comment: Would the sequence shm_open(), mmap(), shm_unlink() help? Will it dispose of the file, but keep the memory allocated and associated file descriptors usable?

Comment: Yes they are still valid file descriptors, you can use it. I was asking same question(anonymous POSIX shared memory). Guess POSIX only supports named shared memory.

Comment: For Linux specific, one can use `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.