# fork() understanding, about execution and children

Tags: unix, parallel-processing, fork

I'm just starting to `fork()` and I'm having some difficulties understanding the parallel execution.  I've found this example code and I want to know if the first time it will go `true` or `false` (I know if `pid1==0` it means it's a child, etc).  I also want to know how many copies (children will be created) and some details on the general execution.

I have tried to run it and added the `return 0;` (my original source didn't have it) just to see if exits... but as you can see it "waits"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VULJZ.png

```
int main(void)
{
    int pid1, pid2, pid3, pid4;
    pid1=fork();
    if (pid1!=0) 
    { 
        pid2=fork(); 
        pid3=fork(); 
        printf("\t\t IF(TRUE) pid1=%d and pid2=%d and pid3=%d\n",
               pid1, pid2, pid3);
    }
    else
    {
        pid4=fork();  
        printf("\nIF(False) FATHER is talking with pid1=%d and pid4=%d\n",
               pid1, pid4);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you just add your screenshot code to your code? Also, include the output prepending with `>` for formatting.  That would help the readability.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that the program isn't hung; the shell spat out its prompt and then the various other processes continued printing too, before they exited.  Your shell is waiting for you to tell it what to do next!  You could add a wait() loop so that processes do not exit until all their children have exited: `int corpse, status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1) printf("Child %d exited 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);`

Comment: Although it is not exactly what you are looking for, but I think [this Q&A about forked processes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16400820/2034041) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program creates five descendant processes, and makes six calls to `printf`, of which four will be the `IF(TRUE)` message and two will be `IF(FALSE)`.  Here is an ASCII-art diagram of the control flow; every time it branches, both sides are executed, with the parent going straight down and the child to the right.  The numbers are the `fork` calls initializing the `pid1`, `pid2`, ... variables, the letters T and F are the `IF(TRUE)` and `IF(FALSE)` messages, and the `_` is the `return 0` at the end of the function.  This program does not wait for anything; all control flow paths reach the `return 0` eventually.

```
|
1
|\------\
2       4
|\--\   |\
3   3   | |
|\  |\  | |
T T T T F F
| | | | | |
_ _ _ _ _ _
```

The output messages may appear in *any order*.  And it's possible that the topmost parent process will exit (returning control to the shell) before all of the descendant processes have written their messages, so (as is visible in your screeenshot) the shell prompt may get jumbled up with the messages, too.

Note that, going by the text of the messages, you have your `if` conditional backward: `pid1 != 0` is true in the *parent*, not the child.

Comment: i asked one of my teacher's today and you are right, each fork() is giving to the child the source code from that specific line and below from where it whas called, and i remember drawing the tree like you have, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Both true and false will be used on the first time.

`fork()` copies the program (creates 1 child) and both programs continue execution from that point.  The child process will take one branch and the parent the other.

The number of `fork()`s is as follows:

You start with 1 process

After `pid1` -> +1 processes

**Parent Branch**

After `pid4` -> +1 processes

**Child Branch**

After `pid2` -> +1 processes

BOTH of the newly created processes run `fork()` for `pid3`, so after `pid3` -> +2 processes

You get 5 children + the original process.

Comment: i tryed to "simulated" the programm execution and i think it wil create 3 childs, plus one of the child will make another, i really can't see why it will make 2^14, i think each fork creates a child plus the father,

Comment: my thought process:
the first fork() will make child1 + father,
now the child1 will go FALSE on the if() and it will create a grandchild,
now the father will go on TRUE and will make two more childs
i'm i wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that, the edit view doesn't show the question and I remembered the code wrong.  See my updated answer.