# Do file systems have other components rather than files and directories?

Tags: python, filesystems

I have seen this python snippet in a video tutorial which checks if the listed item is a directory or a file:

```
for item in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isfile(item):
        # do something
    elif os.path.isdir(item):
        # do somethin
    else:
        # What is this case ?!
```

is it possible that the else statement could be hit?

Comment: There's also `islink`, but [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) state that `isfile` and `isdir` follow links anyway, and `ismount`.

Answer (score 4):

As @sisoft says, the simple answer is yes: there do exist file systems that support file types other than files and directories.

The longer answer, if you're interested, is that the types supported by a file system vary wildly with the file system. UNIX treats a huge number of things as a 'file' (meaning an object in the file system) and so has many types. Windows has a more restricted set of objects (files, directories and links only I believe (no source))

The POSIX specification (implemented by many file systems) for a file system doesn't specify what objects it must support([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550253/what-is-posix-compliance-for-filesystem)).

Generally, file system is a fairly open term that can refer to any object store. The objects that it stores could be anything.

If you'd like to learn more about file systems, there is a great chapter in [Operating Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321117891) which gives an easily accessible introduction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There are other types, like pipes, sockets, device nodes.
For example `isfile()` and `isdir()` returns False for most files from `/dev`.

You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types at first.

Comment: Yes exactly. I remember that I did by mistake `vi /dev/sda` and the vi prompt said `/dev/sda is not a file`

Comment: Are you talking about the filesystem entry types or about generic file types? Cause the answer depends on what is meant by the filesystem - is it something that starts with / on Unix  or it is a particular filesystem as a data layout (say ex3 or NTFS).

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible that the else statement could be hit?

Your code fragment uses a narrow definition of files and directories: [`os.stat(path)` (follows symlinks) is successful and either `S_ISREG` or `S_ISDIR` are true correspondingly](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/db2dc5e31cc8e309457d6dd0795b55acab79fbb4/Lib/genericpath.py#L25-L45).

`else` clause may be triggered for non-existing paths or due to permission errors for regular files and directories.

[POSIX defines the following marcos](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html):

```
S_ISBLK(m)
Test for a block special file.
S_ISCHR(m)
Test for a character special file.
S_ISDIR(m)
Test for a directory.
S_ISFIFO(m)
Test for a pipe or FIFO special file.
S_ISREG(m)
Test for a regular file.
S_ISLNK(m)
Test for a symbolic link.
S_ISSOCK(m)
Test for a socket.
```

i.e., in addition to a regular file and a directory, there could be sockets, symlinks, pipes, block/character devices:

```
>>> import os
>>> import stat
>>> stat.S_ISBLK(os.stat('/dev/sda').st_mode)
True
```

There could exist other objects that have meaning only for a particular filesystem.