# Can isfile() and isdir() functions both evaluate to False?

Tags: python

Is it possible for a file `f` that `os.path.isfile(f)` and `os.path.isdir(f)` both evaluate to false?

What would a third category be named in this case?

Szenario:
I have created a contentless file using `touch` on ubuntu 18.04, which definitely is not a directory. Python (version 3.5) nevertheless returns false on `isfile(f)`.

Edit: It turns out that the file indeed returned True, the earlier output was a small mistake in my code.

The question still remains as I thought about it this way:

1. I have a set (Set A) of all files in a directory.
2. I create a subset via isfile filtering (Set B).
3. I create a subsets via isdir filtering (Set C).

   Would the union of B and C be equal to A?

Comment: try it on a symlink. or on a device file. or a socket. or something other than a file or directory you find on your filesystem. but if `f` is a file as you state, `isfile` will return `True`.

Comment: "file f" - that would make `isfile` always true and `isdir` always false.

Comment: @U9-Forward Dude, all I want to know is specified in the question.

Comment: To clarify, does the file in question definitely exist? Can you please add example code of how exactly you produce this case?

Comment: @Lomtrur file has been created with touch (added the szenario above)

Comment: I think this is a valid question. As I read it, Minato does not try to make it return `False`. OP just wants to know if you have to check for different possibilities in your code. @U9-Forward, your comments seem unneccessary aggressive and abusive.

Comment: @Minato: the `f` in your example, is it a string? what does `type(f)` say?

Comment: This is a pretty clear question and should not be closed as unclear. What it *should* be closed as is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741079/do-file-systems-have-other-components-rather-than-files-and-directories

Comment: @ChristianKönig Sorry, i removed all my comments, i didn't see all the edits, and i undownvoted, and upvoted your comment

Comment: @ChristianKönig And voted to reopen..

Comment: @ChristianKönig And upvoted the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for a file f that os.path.isfile(f) and os.path.isdir(f) both evaluate to false?

yes .. if you ask for existence `os.path.exists(f)`.

EDIT: to answer your more detalied question ..

> Would the union of B and C be equal to A?

Normaly yes .. if you can assert that none of them is deleted in the meantime.

Take into account that dead links are not *exists*, which means that `os.path.exists(deadlink)` of a (existing) link pointing to a dead end results in `False` while `os.path.islink(deadlink)` results in `True`, no matter if it points to a existing object or a dead end.

Comment: [There is also at least one bug that can cause this behaviour on Windows.](https://bugs.python.org/issue33105) I haven't found anything for Ubuntu.