# Is using streams over pipes under Linux worthwhile?

Tags: c, linux

When using pipes to communicate between processes under Linux, is there any benefit to creating streams from the pipes using `fdopen` and then using `fread`/`fwrite` on the streams instead of `read`/`write`?

Comment: Do you mean if it is worthy to create [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)?

Comment: stdio.h gives you buffering and formatted IO (fprintf/fscanf). It is your choice to use them or not.

Comment: @Peregring-lkm, no.

Comment: if you use fread and fwrite then it makes your code platform independent.

Comment: Define "benefit". Are you asking about efficiency or something else?

Answer (score 0):

## Standard Input/Output (stdio)

`fdopen` is part of the `stdio` library. From [`stdio` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html), you get this:

> The standard I/O library provides a simple and efficient buffered
>          stream I/O interface.  Input and output is mapped into logical data
>          streams and the physical I/O characteristics are concealed.  The
>          functions and macros are listed below; more information is available
>          from the individual man pages.

And then:

> **The stdio library is a part of the library libc and routines are
>          automatically loaded as needed by the compilers cc(1) and pc(1)**.  The
>          SYNOPSIS sections of the following manual pages indicate which
>          include files are to be used, what the compiler declaration for the
>          function looks like and which external variables are of interest.

Being part of the **libc**, it means that programs written using these functions will compile in all standard-conforming compilers. If you write a program using **open/write** (which are [POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/i-never-really-understood-what-is-posix)), then your program will only run on POSIX systems.

So you could reason that **(a)** it's worth because of portability and **(b)** it's not worth it if you're only using it in Linux, because then using `open/write` you remove a whole lot of abstraction (from stdio) - keep in mind that under [GNU GLibC](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) `open/write` are wrappers around the syscalls, you're not actually calling then directly, so a small amount of abstraction is present.

Answer (score 0):

Writing into a pipe involves a syscall and a context switch. If you would like to minimize these, you may like to use `stdio` functions to do buffering in the user space, and this also allows for formatted output with `fprintf`.

Answer (score -1):

A `FILE*` created out of a file descriptor using `fdopen()` will provide the additional features of buffering, error checking (`feof()`, `ferror()`) etc which you may or may not need.
I don't see any benefit of using a `fdopen()` mainly because the pipe itself will do certain level of buffering (on modern Linux, it's 64K).
Besides, in most use-cases where pipes are used in [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), buffering isn't desirable.

So, I don't see any benefit of using `fdopen()`. Using [`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) & [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) directly will be sufficient and often desirable in IPC.

Comment: _the pipe itself will do certain level of buffering_ - pipe is a buffer, maintained by the kernel.

Comment: The buffering provided by using the `fxxxx` calls happens in the user process, whereas each `write`/`read` requires a system call. The former can be faster in the case of a lot of small writes/reads.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin "pipe is a buffer" is misleading. A pipe is a communications channel that _is_ buffered.

Comment: @davmac Pipe is both or either, depends on the context and the level of detail.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin pipe is *not* a buffer. It definitely has a buffer and is maintained by the kernel. Linux man page states: "Data written to the write end of the pipe is buffered by the kernel until it is read from the read end of the pipe."

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin if you insist. The [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe) says that "an anonymous pipe is a simplex FIFO communication channel that may be used for one-way interprocess communication (IPC)". Personally I think this is the essence of what "pipe" means and that any buffering is a secondary matter.