# Where do I find the list of RFCs that Red Hat uses in building RHEL?

Tags: standards, rhel

I am working on a project that wants me to document the relevant ISO standards and RFCs that apply to the components of the system.  One of those components is RHEL, so I need to find a list of the standards that apply.  Anybody know who to ask at Red Hat?  So far, no luck getting to a customer rep.

Thanks...Pete

Comment: They will have no such list. RedHat does not implement RFCs. They aggregate Linux components, some of which are implemented to (more or less) abide by RFCs. In practical terms, essentially every RFC in force will have some influence on some package that you can install on RedHat.

Comment: IETF RFCs are typically for network and internet-related formats and protocols. You may be interested in [POSIX](https://linuxhint.com/posix-standard/), which is an IEEE standard. See also [What is the meaning of “POSIX”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1780599/6002174) on Stack Overflow.