# How to run python on my own operating system?

Tags: python, machine-learning, operating-system

I am planning on making an OS and am planning to run some python machine learning scripts on it. How can I get python to support said OS?
Thanks

Comment: You can compile it from here: https://github.com/python/cpython but it requires you to write your own compiler haha :)

Comment: See also [what is the meaning of POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31865755/2626313)