# How to check if file is executable in C++?

Tags: c++, api, unix

So I have a path to file. How to check if it is executable? (unix, C++)

Comment: "executable", what does it mean for you? E.g. Python script file (with shebang like #!/usr/bin/python)?

Comment: Duplicate of your earlier post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719438/how-to-find-out-if-path-leads-to-executable-file

Comment: `stat()` for example?

Answer (score 8):

access(2):

```
#include <unistd.h>

if (! access (path_name, X_OK))
    // executable
```

Calls to stat(2) have higher overhead filling out the struct.  Unless of course you need that extra information.

Comment: This is probably a better solution than mine; I had forgotten about `access()`.

Comment: Are you saying that access() is not implemented by itself doing a stat() and getpid(), getuid(), getgid()? I would imagine that the overhead is pretty much the same.

Comment: The implementation of access() is unknown.  But that's not what I said - filling out a stat struct has a cost.

Comment: This will return true for a directory.

Answer (score 6):

Check the permissions (status) bits.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

bool can_exec(const char *file)
{
    struct stat  st;

    if (stat(file, &st) < 0)
        return false;
    if ((st.st_mode & S_IEXEC) != 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But this answers "can *someone* execute the file?" not "can *I* execute the file?" Perhaps the OP should consider [access(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access).

Comment: Note that the fact that the EXEC bit is set does not mean you can execute a file. You need to also test the owner and group and if you have Secure Linux then the security settings which stat does not give you.

Answer (score 4):

There is a caveat at the bottom of the man page for access(2):

> CAVEAT
>        Access() is a potential security hole and should never be used.

Keep in mind that a race condition exists between the time you call access() with a path string and the time you try to execute the file referred by the path string, the file system can change. If this race condition is a concern, first open the file with open() and use fstat() to check permissions.

Comment: I'm not sure that open()/fstat() closes the race condition that the man page describes. The race is that, in the OP's situation, the file could change its executability between access() and execv(). With your work-around, it could still change between fstat() and execv(). I think the man page authors' intent is that you ought to just go ahead and call execv() -- if it fails, then you have your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to call the POSIX function [`stat(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) and examine `st_mode` field of the [`stuct stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html) object it would fill in.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to look at [stat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [access(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access), which checks for permissions relative to the current process's uid and gid:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int can_exec(const char *file)
{
    return !access(file, X_OK);
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
    while(av++,--ac) {
        printf("%s: %s executable\n", *av, can_exec(*av)?"IS":"IS NOT");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Blender - according to [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/access.2.html), yes, this will work on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You might use this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int is_executable_file(char const * file_path)
{
    struct stat sb;
    return 
        (stat(file_path, &sb) == 0) &&  
        S_ISREG(sb.st_mode) && 
        (access(file_path, X_OK) == 0);
}
```

Why not just `access()`? Since it will accept directories which can be recursed - which are not executable files.

If you want to be a little more standard-friendly and can use C++17, try:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <unistd.h>

int is_executable_file(const std::filesystem::path& file_path)
{
    return 
        std::filesystem::is_regular_file(file_path) &&
        (access(file_path.c_str(), X_OK) == 0);
}
```